# Sorting an array of maps by a key in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting, rxjs

I'm attempting to sort an array of maps by a particular key/value within the maps.

```
Map<string, string>[]
```

I get back the following error,

*Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'*'

I'm trying to make heads or tails of this error but I feel like I'm not returning the correct value somewhere. I think my code looks mostly correct. I'm more concerned I may be trying to do something that is more difficult than I realize. Here is my code. I hard-coded the key for now just try and work through the problem and that key does exists. Any insight would be great. Thanks for looking.

```
sortGridData(data$ : Observable<Map<string, string>[]>) : Observable<Map<string, string>[]> {
        const sortedData$ = combineLatest([data$, this.sort$]).pipe(
            map(([data, sort]: [Map<string, string>[], SortDescriptor[]]) => {
                data.sort((item1, item2) => {
                    return this.compareObjects(item1, item2, 'version')
                })
                return data;
            })
        );

        return sortedData$;
    }

    compareObjects(object1 : Map<string, string>, object2: Map<string, string>, key) {
        let item1 = object1.get(key);
        let item2 = object2.get(key);

        const obj1 = item1.toUpperCase()
        const obj2 = item2.toUpperCase()

        if (obj1 < obj2) {
            return -1
        }
        if (obj1 > obj2) {
            return 1
        }
        return 0
    }
```

Sort Grid data is called at another point in my component. I'm not sure that is entirely relevant.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mA724w), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the data is coming from some state-management observable based library.

If my assumption is correct the issue is because you try to mutate immutable element, what i mean is that `Array.sort` is making changes over the existing array named `data`, a.k.a. it mutates it, and because the data itself is an immutable array (read-only no modification allowed) you are receiving this error.

The thing that will most-likely solve your issue is to create a copy of the `data` array, and after that sort the elements inside this new copy.

```js
sortGridData(data$ : Observable<Map<string, string>[]>) : Observable<Map<string, string>[]> {
        const sortedData$ = combineLatest([data$, this.sort$]).pipe(
            map(([data, sort]: [Map<string, string>[], SortDescriptor[]]) => {
                // here we create a new array, that can be mutated
                const dataCopy = [...data];
                
                dataCopy.sort((item1, item2) => {
                    return this.compareObjects(item1, item2, 'version')
                })
                return dataCopy;
            })
        );

        return sortedData$;
    }
```

If this doesn't solve your issue please provide some more context about from where is the `sortGridData` being called, and to what is the `data$` referring to, when the function is called.